# AngularJS : factory $http.get request keep getting html file as return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, angularjs-factory

may i know why i keep getting html file as return from my angular factory ?

this is my backend route

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header' });
  }
  var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
  if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired' });
  }
  req.user = payload.sub;
  next();
}

app.get('/api/me', ensureAuthenticated, userHandler.getMe);
```

this is the getMe function calling from userHandler

```
 this.getMe = function(req, res, next){
          // retrieve data from database by using req.user as id
          User.findById(req.user, function(err, user) {
            res.send(user);
         });
    }
```

in my service.js( i have try debug in here by changing the route '/api/me' to some other route it still return status 200 when there's no such route exist in route on my back end.

```
app.factory('Account', function($http) {
    return {
      getProfile: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/me'); 
      },
      updateProfile: function(profileData) {
        return $http.put('/api/me', profileData);
      }
    };
  });
```

in my controller

```
$scope.getProfile = function() {
      Account.getProfile()
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.user = data;
          console.log(data) // this print out the html file 
        })
        .error(function(error) {
          alert("something is wrong when retriving your data");
        });
    };
    $scope.getProfile();
```

console.log(data) give me this 
[image]

in the network tab 
[image]

can anyone help me with this ? may i know is there any method to debug this kind of problem ? thanks !

Comment: See the "Network" tab of developer pane, from there investigate the sent request.

Comment: server may send html page as response data. you may use  headers: {'Content-Type':}

Comment: @UlukBiy hi thanks for your reply, i see the same thing in the network tab preview, just like the console.log(data)

Comment: Are you using HTML5 mode to remove the # from your url? Maybe your server isn't configured to handle it. So you getting index.html back rather than the end point.

Comment: @Steve hi, yes i'm doing that. may i know what is the possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up it caused by my nodejs app.js file i mess up the order of the line.

```
  "use strict";
// all environments
app.use(compress());
app.use(require('prerender-node'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(favicon());
app.use(errorHandler());
app.enable('trust proxy');

//for html5 mode 
app.get('*',function(req, res){ // this 
  res.sendFile('master.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/') });
});
routes(app, mongoose); // and this
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure that MongoDB is running.');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

it should be

```
routes(app, mongoose); // this 
 //for html5 mode 
 app.get('*',function(req, res){ // and this 
 res.sendFile('master.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/') });
 });
```

i'm very sorry for wasting your time. i really do, however, i'm really grateful for the effort you guys dedicated to help me solve this question. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

just send json in response

```
functionensureAuthenticated(req,res,next){
if(!req.headers.authorization){
    return res.json { status :'401',
        message: 'PleasemakesureyourrequesthasanAuthorizationheader'
    };
}vartoken=req.headers.authorization.split('')[
    1
];varpayload=jwt.decode(token,
config.TOKEN_SECRET);if(payload.exp<=moment().unix()){
    return res.json{
        status: '401',
        message: 'Tokenhasexpired'
    }
}req.user=payload.sub;next();
```